# Canonical way in Python to add or retrieve meta information to/from docstrings?

Tags: python, metadata, docstring

I'd like to add some meta information to my Python modules' docstrings, such as author, email, version. Is there a canonical way to do that? I searched quite a while, but couldn't find anything with definite authority, here or on the web.

[PEP 426 -- Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) talks about it some. And it looks like `__author__`, `__version__` and some others are recognized by `pydoc` (V2.7). Also, there is `epydoc` and `sphinx-doc`.

Is there a standard way to include such information in the docstring? Or as global variables? If so, is there a list of accepted keywords / variable names?

Example:

```
#########
# Parts
# <description>
#
"""Helper module for selling car parts on the web.
   Author: Sue Baru
   EMail: sb@carparts.com
   Version: 1.0
"""
```

**Update**

This is not really an answer, but I ended up using the `__author__` 'keyword' and nothing else. Versioning is accomplished by being checked into a git repo.

Comment: For love of god, don't use global variables :).

Comment: @BhavishAgarwal -- things like `__version__` are used by *LOTS* of packages.  It's not the best, but I don't think there's anything much better.  It's even mentioned in [PEP3001](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3001/#unification-of-module-metadata).  Ultimately, when it comes to docstrings though, I'm not aware of the various tools following a specific convention.

Comment: @mgilson, for the lack of standard and assuming that this is for internal usage, why not store this info as json string?

Comment: @BhavishAgarwal, agreed. That's why I said I wanted to store this information in the docstring. That way, you also see with help().

Comment: @mgilson, I saw the PEP3001 as well, but figured, since it was from 2006, there might be something more relevant...

Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: @StefanLudwig -- There are function annotations in python3 which are useful for annotating functions, but that's a bit of a different niche I'm afraid.

Comment: @BhavishAgarwal: one thing is a global constant, another is is a global variable; just because global variables are bad (because they change and thus have the ability to cause unexpected side effects) doesn't mean global constants are bad. In fact, almost all constants in source code are global in the first place.

Comment: @StefanLudwig: just one thought though: if you're using `__author__` in the source code, what if a snippet of code has 2 authors? or 3? Why not just rely on `git blame` to dynamically get the author(s) for any given range of lines?

Comment: @ErikAllik: Thanks, I didn't remember `git blame`, I always use `git log`, sometimes in combination with `grep` to get that sort of information. However, we need a way for "regular" users to tell who to contact, if they run into trouble. Not everyone is or wants to be a git. ;-)

Comment: Then these regular users will get out of date or partial information. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx does it this way (using reST):

```
"""A pypi demonstration vehicle.

.. moduleauthor:: Andrew Carter <andrew@invalid.com>

"""
```

See [Documenting Your Project Using Sphinx](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html) and [this cheatsheet](http://openalea.gforge.inria.fr/doc/openalea/doc/_build/html/source/sphinx/rest_syntax.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that out as well, but it seemed too big a hammer - and another tool to use.